# In extjs How to bind store data to grid

Tags: extjs, grid, store

i am working in extjs. i am creating view which is displaying grid.i have created view as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.allQuestionPapers' ,
        {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.paperlist',
    id:'paperId',
    store:'QbqnsStore',
    border:false,
    height:300,
    width:450,
    columns: [
              {
                  text: 'date',
                  width: 150,
                  dataIndex: 'creationTime'
              },
              {
                  text: 'QuestionpaperNo',
                  width: 150,
                  dataIndex: 'questionPaperNo',
              },
              {
                  text: 'Marks',
                  width:150,
                  dataIndex: 'obtainMarks'
              }
              ]
        });
```

This view i am calling on getAllPapers button click. So i have written code as-

```
getAllPapers:function()
    {   
        var getPaperStore=Ext.create('Balaee.store.qb.QbqnsStore');
        proxy=reviewQuestionStore.getProxy();
        Ext.apply(proxy.api,{
            read:'index.php/QuestionBank/qbpaper/getUserAllQuestionPaper',
        });

        var temp2=Ext.getCmp('QbqnsResultmainId');
        temp2.removeAll();
        var papers=Ext.create('Balaee.view.qb.qbqns.allQuestionPapers');
        temp2.add(papers);

    }
```

In above function i am calling required URl to get json as-

```
{" Papers ":[{"questionPaperId":"29","questionPaperNo":"11","userId":"106","allocatedTime":null,"completedTime":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","createDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","obtainMarks":null},{"questionPaperId":"30","questionPaperNo":"11","userId":"106","allocatedTime":null,"completedTime":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","createDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","obtainMarks":null},{"questionPaperId":"31","questionPaperNo":"11","userId":"106","allocatedTime":null,"completedTime":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","createDate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","obtainMarks":null}] }
```

So now store is having this above json data and i want to provide it in grid on view. But grid is not displaying any data. So how to bind store data to grid? what changes i need to make?

Answer (score 6):

We need to bind the store to a grid while initializing itself. I did as below in my case:

```
Ext.define('App.view.activity.ListPanel', {

    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.listPanel',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.ArrayStore'
    ],

    initComponent: function(){

        var activityStore = Ext.create('App.store.Activity');
        activityStore.load(); // this line to load is used when we use proxy in store, if we go with out proxy it is not necessary

        Ext.apply(this, {            
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'grid',                  
                    hideHeaders: true,
                    scroll: false,
                    width: 200,
                    height: 700,
                    store: activityStore,
                    stripeRows:true,
                    columnLines:true,
                    columns:[
                        {text:"Activity Name",flex:1,dataIndex:"activityName"}
                        ]                   
                }]    
        }); 

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Where **App.store.Activity** is defined as(**without proxy**):

```
Ext.define('App.store.Activity', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    id: 'activityStore',
    model: 'App.model.Activity',
    autoLoad: true,
    data : [
            {activityName: 'Bath',    createdBy: 'Spencer', scheduleTime: '7.00'},
            {activityName: 'Breakfast', createdBy: 'Maintz', scheduleTime: '8.00'},
            {activityName: 'Wakeup', createdBy: 'Conran', scheduleTime: '5.00'}
        ]
});`
```

**With Proxy:**

```
Ext.define('App.store.Activity', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    id: 'transactionSummaryStore',
    model: 'App.model.Activity',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'getActivities.htm',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'results'
        } 
    } 
});
```

Where Model is defined as:

```
Ext.define('App.model.Activity', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ {
        name : 'activityName'
    }, {
        name : 'createdBy'
    }, {
        name : 'scheduleTime'
    } ]
});
```